# main language setting does not work

Tags: magento-2.1

On the website I have two languages configured (Polish and English). 
I have set up the main language of the Polish website after entering.

Unfortunately, when I enter the website in the private eye (after clearing browser cookies) the page displayed in English language. 
In Attachment add screenshot  that I have correct configured page display in Polish. [image]